# Trouble understanding children() and :first in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am confused about how the selection of an element in jQuery works using `children()` and the `:first` custom class?

For instance, [**in this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hGDHs/1/), the code `ul > li {hello from nest}` does not get the class `.emphasis` but the `first-child` of top level `ul` gets it. I expected the inner `li` to also get the class.

The commented out line in my jQuery code works as I expect it to.

Comment: The `>` selector only gets the direct desendants. Plus, what is the actual problem here if your code is working?

Comment: @Zenith: please read the question once again. OP *clearly* stated that he cannot get why the 2 lines of JS produce different results.

Comment: @zerkms If the problem is just a matter of selector, then surely Googling the documentation for the selector will show OP why it isn't working?

Comment: @Zenith: if every OP googled before asking then SO would become 95% smaller (and I'm sure 95% is an optimistic estimation)

Comment: @zerkms Lol true, what's ironic is that most of them probably use Google to get to this website, but not for their actual problem..

Comment: @Zenith: what is even more ironic is that in at least half of cases SO proposes a possible solution on the question composition step (when it uses title input as a smart search). Or in the right "Related" bar afterwards

Comment: Relax guys, I did read "Similar Questions" but in none of them, it was written that $() will return a list (its possible that I missed that part) , and :first will return the first one of them. I did knew this is what happens but i was thinking in terms of CSS so I got confused. I also read jQuery official Documentation, but what can i say, When you are confused, you stay confused until you hear that one small point that solves it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:first` selector returns the first matched item among the all selected

So

```
$('ul').children('li:first').addClass('emphasis');
```

selects all children of `ul` which are `li` and then takes the very first of them.

Whereas

```
 $('ul > li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
```

takes all the `li` that are direct children of `ul` and takes every first child of the matched set.

Comment: Aren't *all* children of a `ul` `li` elements?

Comment: @David Thomas: in what case?

Comment: Well, the only valid child element of a `ul` (and `ol`) is an `li` element, and the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method looks only at direct/immediate descendants. So, in *every* case (except those with invalid HTML, I suppose).

Comment: @David Thomas: well, yes, they are. So?

Comment: Oh, I see; I was just wondering about the phrasing of this sentence: "selects all children of `ul` which are `li` and then takes the very first of them." The way it's written implies that there's a chance that the children of a `ul` might *not* be `li` elements is all.

Comment: @David Thomas: I've just tried to explain (using direct translation js -> human) what both lines of OPs code mean using my advanced engrish skills )

Answer (score 0):

jQuery go throw the DOM Tree and found the first `ul`-Tag in this Tag the `first-child` is the `li` and it will get the CSS you made.

So it means the very first of all of them.

With the `ul > li:first-child` jQuery takes every li that is the first child of every `ul` not only the first.